# How to crate nested queries in SQLAlchemy unattached to session?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I want to create a nested Query unattached to any sessions. 
For instance, I have this query (which works fine):

```
sub_query = session.query(User.id, User.city_id).filter(User.age <= 18 ).subquery()

query = session.query(sub_query.c.user_id, City.city_name).join(City, sub_query.c.city_id == City.id)

query.all()
```

but I need it to be unattached to any session, so I wanted to do something like this:

```
sub_query = Query(User.id, User.city_id).filter(User.age <= 18 ).subquery()

query = Query(sub_query.c.user_id, City.city_name).join(City, sub_query.c.city_id == City.id)

query.with_session(session).all()
```

But when I execute this bit of code it doesn't work as expected. When executing the `query = Query(...)` it throws this error:

```
    210             return self._data[key]
    211         except KeyError:
--> 212             raise AttributeError(key)
    213 
    214     def __contains__(self, key):

AttributeError: city_id
```

I would be grateful if someone knows what I'm doing wrong.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that **Query()** doesn't work the same as **session.query()**, while **session.query()** accepts as parameters the columns (in this case) to query, the **Query** takes as the first parameter the tuple of requested columns, so to make this work I had to change that to:

```
sub_query = Query((User.id, User.city_id)).filter(User.age <= 18 ).subquery()

query = Query((sub_query.c.user_id, City.city_name)).join(City, sub_query.c.city_id == City.id)

query.with_session(session).all()
```